# How to set the selection border of a Textfield a certain color in JavaFX?

Tags: java, css, javafx-8

I'm trying to create a Textfield in JavaFX. I would like to use a custom color for the selection of the Textfield. I'm not sure what the property is, so I can only explain it this way. When you select it by default, a sky-bluish color shows up on the border. How do I remove that completely, or set it to a custom color? Here is my CSS code:

```
.login-info {
-fx-border-style: solid;

-fx-accent: red; }
```

Answer (score 0):

The textfield uses -fx-background-color: property to achive that. So by overriding

```
.textfield:focused{
   -fx-background-color : yellow,white;
   -fx-background-insets: 0,3px;
}
```

will make the border color yellow, instead of sky-blue when you click on it.

Comment: I have my own custom stylings for most of the javafx controls in this stylesheet which I have created for a retail shop application, and you can find it here on gitgub. https://github.com/Oshan96/ThogaKade

Comment: The direct link to the stylesheet is, https://github.com/Oshan96/ThogaKade/blob/master/src/lk/edu/ijse/ThogaKadeHibernate/ui/util/css/thogaKade.css